# Joining a PC to a domain amends a number after the domain? So it's not really on the domain

Tags: domain

I'm trying to join a PC to my domain, "aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd". When I join it to the domain, it says "Welcome to the aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd domain!" And I have to restart. However, once I restart, I hover over the network symbol and it says "aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd **2**", which is not the correct domain.

Can someone explain what is happening here and how I fix it so it just says "aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd"? I don't understand why the number is being amended to the domain name after a seemingly successful domain joining with a message that cotains the correct domain. Also, in System, it shows the correct domain without the "2" amended, but I'm still not actually on the domain.

I have taken it on and off the domain several times, including removing it from AD and readding it, and get the same results every time. I'm not sure what more I can try.

Comment: What kind of a domain is it and how are you joining? Why use an IP address and not the domain name? If the network symbol is in the traybar, right-click it, Open Network & Internet settings, click "Change adapter options" and add its screenshot to your post.

Answer (score 0):

> However, once I restart, I hover over the network symbol and it says "aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd 2", which is not the correct domain

That doesn't matter much. The network "name" is only for display purposes; it may be *based on* the AD domain if the system recognizes you're on the same network as a domain controller (or something like that), but it doesn't actually influence your membership in the domain.

(In this case, Windows already has another network remembered with the same name given to it. I believe these are tracked by the "Network Location Awareness" service.)

The domain or workgroup name shown in the 'System' panel (and the ability to log in using a domain account) is what really tells you whether the system is a domain member or not.